# making sprites randomly appear

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to have sprites randomly appear on the screen with out using OOP principles

this code is from a ants demo for AI

```
        if randint(1, 10) == 1:
            leaf = Leaf(world, leaf_image)
            leaf.location = Vector2(randint(0, w), randint(0, h))
            world.add_entity(leaf)



        world.process(time_passed)
        world.render(screen)

        pygame.display.update()
```

Question:
How do I get Sprites on the screen randomly?
I know to blit them
but how without using Object-Oriented

this is the only part my code is missing a way for sprites to randomly appear
this the code to the antstate.py where im getting the code:
http://www.mediafire.com/?5tjswcyl9xt5huj

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question. What is the code doing now? What do you want it to do? You'll have a better chance getting an answer if you can limit your question down to something very specific. Asking people to download what appears to be a large chunk of code from mediafire is a sure way to get your question ignored.

Comment: Why "with out using OOP principles"? `Vector2(randint(0, w), randint(0, h))` generates a random onscreen location (x in 0..screenwidth, y in 0..screenheight); then this is assigned to leaf.location and the leaf is added to 'things in the world'; then every time world.render() is called, everything in the world is told to draw itself.

Answer (score 1):

A sprite is an object. So you need to use some OOP to work with a sprite. Here's an example:

```
# Sample Python/Pygame Programs
# Simpson College Computer Science
# http://cs.simpson.edu/?q=python_pygame_examples

import pygame
import random

# Define some colors
black    = (   0,   0,   0)
white    = ( 255, 255, 255)

# This class represents the ball       
# It derives from the "Sprite" class in Pygame
class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    # Constructor. Pass in the color of the block,
    # and its x and y position
    def __init__(self, color, width, height):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        # Create an image of the block, and fill it with a color.
        # This could also be an image loaded from the disk.
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(color)

        # Fetch the rectangle object that has the dimensions of the image
        # image.
        # Update the position of this object by setting the values
        # of rect.x and rect.y
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

# Initialize Pygame
pygame.init()

# Set the height and width of the screen
screen_width=700
screen_height=400
screen=pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width,screen_height])

# This is a list of 'sprites.' Each block in the program is
# added to this list. The list is managed by a class called 'RenderPlain.'
block_list = pygame.sprite.RenderPlain()

for i in range(50):
    # This represents a block
    block = Block(black, 20, 15)

    # Set a random location for the block
    block.rect.x = random.randrange(screen_width)
    block.rect.y = random.randrange(screen_height)

    # Add the block to the list of objects
    block_list.add(block)
```